# Some questions regarding in-app privacy policy and User Messaging Platform (UMP)

Tags: android, google-play, admob, policy, gdprconsentform

As all we know, google requires to have a inner privacy policy inside the application when the app manages sensitive data, for example, when uses google analytics.

Now, admob displays an alert which tells you that will be mandatory to use a certified messaging platform like admob `User Messaging Platform (UMP)` for displaying a new GDPR alert if your app is trying to display ads.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/13554116?hl=en&sjid=14577619474979543223-EU

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10113207

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy?hl=en#kotlin_3

```
consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this)
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
        this,
        params,
        OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener {
          // The consent information state was updated.
          // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
        },
        OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener {
          // Handle the error.
        })
  }
```

So... now... must apps display two policy dialogs which the user has to consent at the start of the app? it seems to be too much for me, excessive.

Am I losing something?